# Passing data between two userforms doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on a userform that inserts data into a DB. There is a modify button that allows to update data but I want allow confirmation of update with a password. Therefore, in the Code of the modify button, I am calling another userform that prompts the user to enter a password. The problem I am having is that I have created a boolean variable that is set to `True` when the password is correct and to `False` other. When the password is correct, the code for the modify button continues but the `True` info is not transmitted to the first userform

I have seen a lot of similar questions here but none of the answers that I have seen has helped me solve my problem. I have created some public variables in both codes but still does not work

Here is the code for the modify button (First userform)

```
Private Sub modify_Click()
On Error GoTo handler
Dim connec As Object
Dim rst As Object
Dim stringconn As String
Dim sqlupdt As String
Dim modifmat As String
Dim msg

--Some code here

if [condition] then
goto 1
end if

1 password.show

if pwcorr= True then 
goto 2
else
msgbox "Incorrect password"
exit sub
end if

3 --Some code here
end sub
```

and here is the code for the password userform (2nd userform)

```
Public pwcorr
public sub OkBtn_Click()
Dim pw As String
Dim pwin As String
Dim pwcorr As Boolean

pw= "abcde"
pwin = Me.pwin.Text

If pwin = vbNullString Then
MsgBox "No password was entered", vbCritical
ElseIf pwin = pw Then
Me.pwcorr = True
Unload Me
Else
MsgBox "Password incorrect", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Whenever I get to the point where I check `If pwcorr = True` in the first code, the pwcorr is always empty. Don't know why

Comment: You should always use ` Option Explicit` at the top of your code, which would then flag up that `pwcorr` is nor declared in your first userform. You could declare it in your first userform, then use it in the second userform like `userform1.pwcorr = True`.

Comment: Do not use global variables.  Use a global function to pass the data.  Create a public function to set PWCorr and save the value on the modules private variable and a public function to get PWCorr that returns the value from private variable.

Comment: Great Thanks! That actually worked. I did declare my variable pwcorr in the first userform as a public one, but now I have just added the type and the information is passed on between the userforms correctly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jules Why no "Global Variables"?

Comment: Personal experience, global variables makes codes hard to maintain. In a big system, it may not be initialized when you are trying to use it.  I like the factory concept as the values are guaranteed to be initialized properly.